# How to add hotkeys to Windows 10 system setting toggles?

Tags: windows, windows-10, automation, hotkeys, control-panel

There are certain system settings that I toggle regularly, such as enabling and disabling HDR or night light. Is it possible to add hotkeys for these or at least somehow toggle them without the settings app?

Answer (score 0):

To turn Night Light on or off requires a [Registry change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333299/how-to-start-night-light-via-command-in-windows-10). Save a Reg file for each state and add keyboard shortcuts, e.g through Windows links (shortcuts) or a third-party utility such as [Clavier+](http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php). *Caveat:* For security reasons, you'll still need to confirm any Registry change, so it's not a single-click solution.

For [HDR, there are a number of Registry keys](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/95506-change-video-playback-settings-windows-10-a.html) that *might* work, but you also might need to create your own application calling  [HdmiDisplayMode Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.core.hdmidisplaymode)

Comment: Not very smooth solutions, but thanks. I was hoping to be able to do this without having to write my own application.