# Method to enumerate path to Windows 10 system settings screens or folders?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, shortcuts, file-shortcut

I want to accomplish what [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1380042/how-to-add-hotkeys-to-windows-10-system-setting-toggles) entails, except personally I'm open to using more than one single input or keystroke to achieve it.

I'm aware that some (if not all) of the system windows can be invoked via directly calling upon their path, which can then be bound to a shortcut or even directly via run (which, then, makes it accessible for direct keybinding through various different methods, such as .ahk script or peripheral device's OEM softwares).

An example of this would be the `Devices & Printers` screen, which for some reason no longer populates in the Start menu search as an  entry directly; thus, I had to lookup and create a shortcut for it:

`%systemroot%\explorer.exe /e,::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{A8A91A66-3A7D-4424-8D24-04E180695C7A}`

What I'd like to know is, how does one go about actually determining what that path address is?  There may be various screens or functions I'd like to automate my access for (currently, `Ease of Access Mouse Settings`), and at present I can only look them each up individually case-by-case, and that's assuming one exists and has been posted online.  I'd prefer to learn how to catch the proverbial fish myself, if that makes any sense.

Comment: So what are you doing about the LIAR David Postill's sabotage? Hiding like a coward?

Comment: ???  What's going on?  Who's David Postill???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **Control Panel** items, if you don't really need the path but just want a shortcut, the easy way is:

Click in the **Explorer** Address Bar and type (or copy/paste):
`shell:::{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}` to open the **All Tasks** folder, which list all the actions available:
[image]
Right-click any item & select `Create Shortcut` to create a shortcut on your **Desktop**.

The **PowerShell** way to list the System Folder names that (mostly) can be used with the `Shell:` protocol is:

```
(gp (gci HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions).PSPath).Name
```

And here's a recursive romp through the **Control Panel** Namespace:

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$DT = $Shell.Namespace(0)

Function Unfold ($oFolder) {
$oFolder.Items() | ?{ ($_.IsFolder -eq $True) -and ($_.Name -notLike 'Fonts') } | ForEach{
UnFold $_.GetFolder
}
$_.GetFolder.Items() | select Name, Path
}

$DT.Items() | ?{($_.IsFolder -eq $True) -and
        ($_.Name -match 'Control Panel')} | % {
            Unfold $_.GetFolder
} | Out-Gridview
```

For some reason, the paths don't seem to be working with the `Shell:` protocol. Needs further investigation.

[image]