# How can I create a shortcut to a specific Settings page?

Tags: windows-10, file-shortcut

I use a certain page of Windows 10 Settings quite often, so I'm trying to create a shortcut to place it on Desktop or Taskbar.

It is worth noting that the standard Settings shortcut is available, but browsing to a specific page requires extra clicks.

When looking for an answer, I found that `ms-settings:{page_name}` prefix could do the job, but I failed to find a list of page names.

How can I create a shortcut to a specific page? Namely, this one:

[image: Volume Settings page]

Comment: You may or may not find my [question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1524109/method-to-enumerate-path-to-windows-10-system-settings-screens-or-folders) helpful in your search.  Also note, using an intermediary utility (such as AHK) can also help achieve it, even if in the *worst* case (but perhaps most simplistic) you're macro-ing the navigation sequence to the page from a parent settings page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://winaero.com/blog/ms-settings-commands-in-windows-10/):

```
ms-settings:apps-volume
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Can you help?

Comment: I just copied & pasted into `Run` dialog to test. Still works. How are you tryihng to use it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of some commands: [https://update10.info/full-list-of-ms-settings-commands-for-windows-10/#:~:text=%20Full%20list%20of%20ms-settings%20commands%20for%20Windows,security.%20%2013%20Mixed%20reality.%20%20More%20](https://update10.info/full-list-of-ms-settings-commands-for-windows-10/#:%7E:text=%20Full%20list%20of%20ms-settings%20commands%20for%20Windows,security.%20%2013%20Mixed%20reality.%20%20More%20)

What you are looking for is

```
ms-settings:sound
```