# A shortcut on desktop for opening advanced sound output page

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, system-sounds

Basically, I want to get to this page as quickly as possible

[image]

So, **is there a way to get here other than going into settings sound ?**

Comment: A more general question is here: https://superuser.com/questions/1568440/how-can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-a-specific-settings-page

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes.**

You can make a shortcut with this text in the path: `ms-settings:apps-volume` This will directly open this page of settings.

For example - right-click on the desktop, go to "New" and choose "Shortcut." In the field 'type the location of the item' Paste the above address, click next and name the new shortcut. 'OK' and you are done...

**Enjoy!**

Comment: Ah! Genius Despite the comment on my question about there not being a solution, I had faith. Thanks very much

Comment: This seems to not work with last month's windows update. The address is ms-settings:apps-volume but the shortcut trick doesn't work. Any new solution?